# how to make my active tab unclickable in jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs

I would like to make my active tab unclickable, but i don't know how to modify this code below:

```
function initTabs(){
jQuery('ul.tabset').each(function(){
    var _list=jQuery(this);
    var _links=_list.find('a.tab');
    _links.eq(0).addClass('active');
    _links.each(function(){
        var _link=jQuery(this);
        var _href=_link.attr('href');
        var _tab=jQuery(_href);
        if(_link.hasClass('active'))_tab.css({"opacity":1,"display":"block"});
        else _tab.css({"opacity":0,"display":"none"});
        _link.click(function(){
            _links.filter('.active').each(function(){
                jQuery(jQuery(this).removeClass('active').attr('href')).animate({"opacity":0},000,function(){
                    jQuery(this).css({"display":"none"});_link.addClass('active');
                    _tab.css({"display":"block"}).animate({"opacity":1})})
            });
            return false
        })
    })

})
}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

***EDITTED with answer:***

I know the answer now from [Make a link unclickable once it has been clicked - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924026/make-a-link-unclickable-once-it-has-been-clicked-jquery)

I made changes to the code above, and now it works!

```
function initTabs(){
jQuery('ul.tabset').each(function(){
    var _list=jQuery(this);
    var _links=_list.find('a.tab');
    _links.eq(0).addClass('active');
    _links.each(function(){
        var _link=jQuery(this);
        var _href=_link.attr('href');
        var _tab=jQuery(_href);
        if(_link.hasClass('active'))_tab.css({"opacity":1,"display":"block"});
        else _tab.css({"opacity":0,"display":"none"});
        _link.click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                return false;
            } else {
                _links.filter('.active').each(function(){
                    jQuery(jQuery(this).removeClass('active').attr('href')).animate({"opacity":0},000,function(){
                        jQuery(this).css({"display":"none"});_link.addClass('active');
                        _tab.css({"display":"block"}).animate({"opacity":1})})
                });
            }   
            return false
        })
    })

})
```

}

Comment: What does "unclickable" mean?

Comment: How did you initialize the tabs initially? i.e., what selector did you call .tabs() on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the answer now from [Make a link unclickable once it has been clicked - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924026/make-a-link-unclickable-once-it-has-been-clicked-jquery)

I made changes to the code above, and now it works!

```
function initTabs(){
jQuery('ul.tabset').each(function(){
    var _list=jQuery(this);
    var _links=_list.find('a.tab');
    _links.eq(0).addClass('active');
    _links.each(function(){
        var _link=jQuery(this);
        var _href=_link.attr('href');
        var _tab=jQuery(_href);
        if(_link.hasClass('active'))_tab.css({"opacity":1,"display":"block"});
        else _tab.css({"opacity":0,"display":"none"});
        _link.click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                return false;
            } else {
                _links.filter('.active').each(function(){
                    jQuery(jQuery(this).removeClass('active').attr('href')).animate({"opacity":0},000,function(){
                        jQuery(this).css({"display":"none"});_link.addClass('active');
                        _tab.css({"display":"block"}).animate({"opacity":1})})
                });
            }   
            return false
        })
    })

})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the tab index that you want disabled into the tabs() function.

$("#tabs").tabs({disabled : [1]});

http://jsfiddle.net/PCCrb/1/
​